# Phpmyadmin uses custom query on loading a table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a problem...

In my database I have a table called users. Each user has a lot of data (columns). Now when I click on the table to show It uses the default query: `SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 1920`. Because of the Limit it tries to show 1920 rows on 1 page.

This causes a very slow response of the page and it takes a while to load. I also get this message "Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration."

How can I reset the default query on this table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to use adminer in place of phpmyadmin
here is the link to download, https://www.adminer.org/
Adminer is less in size(just one file) compair to phpmyadmin and way to faster compair with phpmyadmin and it provides all features that phpmyadmin provides
if you are using windows then just put that downloaded file in your ht docs and if linux than /var/www/html/
and that's all.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAxfD.png)

Comment: I am looking for a solution, not an alternative!